# jQuery - Ajax submit JSON data in GET

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Here is what I've tried:

**JS:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    data: JSON.stringify( { data: 'bla' } ),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( data ) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function( data ) {
        alert('error: ' + data);
    }
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

    if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' )
    {
        $data = json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input') );

        echo json_encode( $data );
    }

?>
```

**Output:**

```
null
```

---

If you swap the **GET** with a **POST** instead it works like a charm. "Why not just use the POST instead?", I use POST to perform inserts into the database. I have an inkling feeling it might be because it forcefully wants the GET data in this kind of format: `email=bob@mctest.com&firstname=Bob&lastname=Mctest`. I don't know why though because the content type is set as *application/json*, this is somewhat perplexing. Just to add something here from my last edit, the `php://input` is empty in other words it's not sending any data to it but it still works without problems using curl GET from the terminal.

When I run a curl GET command from the terminal using the JSON content type it works like a charm and spits out the data without issue i.e. `curl -v -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"data":"bla"}' http://codes.local/test.php`

I'm not sure how helpful this will be but I found a PHP Fiddle site and pasted the example code in there just to make it easier for everyone, here is the link: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/u4b-xkh

Thank you very much for any help.

---

**Edit:** Fixed the spell error in 'application/json' pointed out by SilverBlade and updated the PHP Fiddle link (null output still persists in other words still not working). The problem, which I should have stated above, is the `php://input` is actually empty there is no data in there at all when posted via jQuery - no issues when used in-conjunction with curl GET.

---

Edit2: I'm not using IIS, thank you to robertdeniro (heh) for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicions were accurate and the cause of the problem was jQuery $.ajax/$.get was forcing query strings when using GET even when you've set the content type as JSON, makes no sense but I will have to dissect the manuals to find out why that is.

Here is my working code with a workaround that works with curl GET and $.ajax/$.get.

**JS:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'manage.php',
    data: 'user=bla',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( data ) {
        // code here...
    }
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$get = !empty( $_GET ) ? json_decode( json_encode( $_GET ) ) : json_decode( file_get_contents('php://input') );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your content type has a spell error,

```
contentType: 'appllication/json; charset=UTF-8',
```

It should be

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
```

Secondly, you may check with specifying the URL.

Comment: Hi SilverBlade thank you for your reply. I fixed that typo and updated the PHP fiddle and everything else, sorry for the embarrasing mistake there, I was copy-pasting a simplified version of my code so it's easier to go through. FYI you don't have to specify a URL if it's being posted to itself.

Answer (score 1):

SilverBlade may have found your issue, but there is still a communication issue between XHR and PHP. PHP is required to return the correct headers or else strange things can happen with jQuery interpretation.

Try:

header('Content-type: application/json');

Comment: Chopped that in there as well (it's in the latest PHP fiddle) no dice as well =(

Answer (score 0):

Use $.get & $.post instead of $.ajax, life would be much easier. Like this:

```
$.get(request_url, { param: value }, function(data){
  // callback here
}, 'json')
```

Comment: I'll have to check that one out I've barely touched $.get and I'm not sure if it does contentType. I'll give that a shot later today. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: The last parameter 'json' stands for contentType 'application/json'. jQuery supports most used contentTypes in $.get and $.post. Check the API doc and have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean that you can't use a POST because you're using POST for database inserts.
POST **is** for sending data to the server & probably why the server is ignoring data in the GET - because it's not required to process data in a GET.
If you are already using POST then you can extend it - like your json could have 2 properties - Action & Data.
Action = [dbInsert, dbSomethingElse, fileWrite, etc]
Data would be the raw data.
You would take different code paths based on Action 
I don't know what web server you're using but IIS ignores data in a GET - regardless of 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm doing RESTful behaviour (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) and repurposing POST as an insert and PUT as an update. I'm not using IIS I'll chuck that on the top post as this is pretty important factor as well.